# Kafka and Microservices using Producer Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

> I need to use Apache Kafka in my project of Micro-Services. I need my one micro-service to produce data and another to consume the same data. How can I make Kafka do the same between the two services

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to take a look at [Spring Cloud Stream](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/) as it does exactly what you need.

From docs:

> Framework for building message-driven microservices. Spring Cloud Stream builds upon Spring Boot to create DevOps friendly microservice applications and Spring Integration to provide connectivity to message brokers. Spring Cloud Stream provides an opinionated configuration of message brokers, introducing the concepts of persistent pub/sub semantics, consumer groups and partitions across several middleware vendors. This opinionated configuration provides the basis to create stream processing applications.
>
> By adding @EnableBinding to your main application, you get immediate connectivity to a message broker and by adding @StreamListener to a method, you will receive events for stream processing.